# Running a foreach loop with the Format Table Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I am trying to import a csv file, format the result as a table & finally run a foreach loop on each row in the table. The Import and format table piece works fine but I cannot get the foreach working.

The below works as expected:

```
$csvFile="C:\cvsFile.csv"
$table = Import-Csv $csvFile | Format-Table
```

But when I try to do a simple foreach on the $table variable the result set is blank (It doesn't throw any errors).

```
$csvFile="C:\cvsFile.csv" $table = Import-Csv $csvFile | Format-Table
foreach($record in $table) {    Write-Host $record.Field1 }
```

Is it possible to work with the output of Format-Table this way?

Answer (score 2):

use the format-* cmdlets to format the output (display) of your results, and they should be the last cmdlet used in a pipe !
What you want may be something like this :

```
$c=Import-Csv c:\csv.csv
$c | foreach {
    $_ | format-table #all columns
    $_.Field1 #one column
}
```